# Why can't assign const initialize while compile by pointer

Tags: c++

I'm curious about why my research result is strange

```
#include <iostream>

int test()
{
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    /*include either the next line or the one after*/
    const int a = test(); //the result is 1:1
    const int a = 0; //the result is 0:1

    int* ra = (int*)((void*)&a);
    *ra = 1;
    std::cout << a << ":" << *ra << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

why the constant var initialize while runtime can completely change, but initialize while compile will only changes pointer's var?

Comment: You have undefined behavior here.

Comment: The behaviour on attempting to modify an object originally declared as `const` through a pointer that's had `const`-ness cast away from it is undefined. Probably a duplicate out there somewhere on this, although to my mind at least that's not a reason to downvote this well-written question.

Comment: the question would be better if you posted code that does compile. It took me some seconds to realize that you only have one of the two lines. Maybe add a `//` in front of one of them

Comment: @idclev463035818: Do feel empowered to make the necessary edits. Make sure you get them right though :-) oops.

Comment: Actually I'm rolling back - the UB in the code makes the output sensitive to very many things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function isn't really that relevant here. In principle you could get same output (0:1) for this code:

```
int main() {
    const int a = 0;
    int* ra = (int*)((void*)&a);
    *ra = 1;
    std::cout << a << ":" << *ra;
}
```

`a` is a `const int` not an `int`. You can do all sorts of senseless c-casts, but modifiying a `const` object invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

By the way in the above example even for `std::cout << a << ":" << a;` the compiler would be allowed to emit code that prints `1:0` (or `42:3.1415927`). When your code has undefinded behavior anything can happen.

PS: the function and the different outcomes is relevant if you want to study internals of your compiler and what it does to code that is not valid c++ code. For that you best look at the output of the compiler and how it differs in the two cases (https://godbolt.org/).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question completely.

Comment: @Waqar which part are you missing? It tries to explain that it is pointless to answer the question completely. Also to fully answer, OP would have to say what compiler they are using

Comment: What you wrote is totally correct But I am having trouble understanding why it is `0:1` in one case and `1:1` in the other.

Comment: @Waqar i wrote on the answer that one would have to look at the output of the compiler, but as OP didn't say what compiler they are using I cannot answer this part correctly. Its not a question about c++ but about the specific compiler

Comment: I can see that it is doing `mov esi, 1` in one case, and `xor esi, esi` in the other(using clang(trunk) godbolt). Why does it do that? That is the part I am confused about. In the C++ code, they are both 0,  so why?

Comment: I am using VC++

Comment: @Waqar compilers are not made to compile invalid code. When you still ask them to do it strange things can and will happen

Comment: @Waqar to fully understand the "why" you need to dig deep into the implementation of the compiler and in the end this wont tell you anything about C++

Comment: @AlanJian which version? What compiler options did you use? But anyhow, I wont be able to answer the deeper reason behind this output. I personally am more concerned about (correct) C++ and I don't know much about compilers nor am I fluent in reading assembly

Comment: Maybe you are right. But I will still give it a try, because it is just so unsettling that one `0` remains `0` but the other becomes `1`.

Comment: I use VC++ 14.26.28720.3

Comment: And I tested it on linux it causes Segmentation Fault, I think it because Linux has .rodata segment, but windows doesn't

Comment: yes @AlanJian that's correct. On linux it segfault quickly like it should!!

Comment: And in my addition research, if I create another pointer to const, the value of dereference is still wrong in Windows

Comment: @Waqar, it has to do with the fact that `const int a = 0;` is a literal, whereas `const int a = test();` is just a constant *variable*. The literal a can be replaced with 0 by the compiler everywhere (easy optimization). You will get the same behavior if you change `test()` to be `constexpr`.

Comment: @Waqar: Yes it does: attempting to rationalise or define undefined behaviour is futile.

Comment: "attempting to rationalise or define undefined behaviour is futile." - I really don't understand this mindset. By modifying a const variable, you are circumventing the *contract* upon which the compiler is allowed to do optimizations and assumptions. IMO, It is perfectly reasonable to want to understand what are the breaking points and what could *reasonably* happen due to UB.

Comment: @MikaelH its the mindset that cares about C++ (the one I am also following). If you care about internals of the compiler then go ahead, but as already mentioned, it wont tell you anything about the language. I want to write code that can run anywhere compiled with any compiler, now and in 10 years from now, hence understanding the effects of UB really does not help me anything

Comment: @MikaelH btw "what could reasonably happen due to UB" it is anything. One could write a standard compliant compiler that makes this code output `"Haha you wont fool me. a is const :P"`.

Comment: That would not be *reasonable*. Knowing what a compiler does if you do **not** modify a const variable, you *would* be able to *reason* what would happen *if* you broke the contract. Anyway, I get your point.

Answer (score 0):

It is undefined behavior to cast a `const` variable and change it's value. If you try, anything can happen.

Anyway, what seems to happen, is that the compiler sees `const int a = 0;`, and, depending on optimization, puts it on the stack, but replaces all usages with 0 (since `a` will not change!). For `*ra = 1;`, the value stored in memory actually changes (the stack is read-write), and outputs that value.

For `const int a = test();`, dependent on optimization, the program actually calls the function `test()` and puts the value on the stack, where it is modified by `*ra = 1`, which also changes a.

Comment: unspecified is not the same as undefined. If it was unspecified you would just get any result. undefined is worse because it affects all of the code (a valid c++ code has no undefined behavior)

Comment: @idclev463035818 Okay, I will remove that part. I don't think anything else was wrong though, so I will keep the post here in spite of the downvotes.

Comment: didn't vote, but I think your second paragraph is only speculations without any evidence